# What is this font for the numbers?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, font

I recently commented on a question and I used the proper MathJax formatting for the numbers and letters:

[image: picture1]

Some minutes later my net became a little laggy and I refreshed the page. Then I lost my connection for a few seconds. The font of numbers changed a little for me as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: picture2]

Of course I refreshed the page again after my connection came back and the font got fixed.

What is the name of that incorrect font? Is it being used in math.SE or any other websites or applications?

Also, why did the format change when the connection was unstable?

Comment: Links, to see if it's just you? (very likely)....Looks like math sans serif to me, like so: $\mathsf{k}$ (`\mathsf{k}`).

Comment: Why did the MathJax format convert to the math sans serif format when I didn't had a stable connection?

Comment: Without details of your interface and set-up, it is impossible to know.

Comment: A few minutes ago I tried this: ```\mathsf{k}{2}``` and the 2 became MathJax!

Comment: What are the interface and set-up?

Comment: How are you viewing the site? What operating system? What version? The site doesn't do the same thing for everyone. It attempts to respond to your interface and your setup,

Comment: I'm currently on phone (Google Chrome). I will try on Windows too.

Comment: Telling me in comments is useless.

Comment: You can read a bit about how MathJax deals with fonts [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html). In particular, it will sometimes "ask the browser to provide the glyph from a system font". Possibly this is what happened here - the unstable connection meant that MathJax was unable to load the correct glyph, so used the fallback option of asking the browser.

Answer (score 3):

From searching on a font detecting website (found by google) the font in question is [Roboto Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?preview.text=4%20k.%202%203), see comparison:

> [image]

The reason it used this font when the connection wasn't good is probably due to the "Fast Preview" setting:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably a *sans-serif* font like `\mathsf{k}`.$$\mathsf{k}$$
Edit: When the connection was unstable it probably displayed it as *sans-serif* as it did not know what font it was suposed to be, so resorted to a "default" font.

Comment: Is there a reason that MathJax format converted to the sans-serif when the connection was unstable?

Comment: A few minutes ago I tried this: ```\mathsf{2}{k}``` and surprisingly the k became MathJax. I don't know if it helps to find the reason...

Comment: @EtackSxchange In your expression only the 2 is inside the mathsf braces. So the k will resort to the usual font.